# What mod has the "gantrylargescalablevariant" part in KSP?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program, mod-identification

gantrylargescalablevariant is a part in a craft I downloaded, and I don't have the mod for it. Unfortunately, I don't know which mod does. What mod has that part in *KSP*?

Comment: Does the craft info page not have a description of what was used to make it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrtdRoqUeOU - there is a list of mods at the end, I am sure I used them all, let me know if you think I might have missed some?

Comment: How would we know?  We don't know what mods you're using.

Comment: fair enough :P let me get a screenshot

Comment: No, there's nothing here for us to do.  Compare your mod list versus the one in the video.  Add the ones you don't have.  Beyond that, we can't help.

Comment: maybe, i don't know

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the video maker, if you have all the mods listed.  Because there's no way we're going to know what would be missing, if his list isn't complete.

Comment: Try KerbalX. It does not show in the ckan at the video and it has a rescale mod and other legacy parts required. It may be the one missing.

Comment: KSP loading right now, downloading it with compatibility issues was terrible, ckan was wierd, idk... I still have hope though :P

Comment: OMGOMG IT WORKED! I don't have the words for how happy I am xDD thank you so much!

Comment: Mm, apparently I can only accept my own answer tommorow, and I can't just close the discussion. Nice. Help mods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! Ckan didn't actually show infernal robotics legacy parts, that would be important xD thanks to vianna77